# Can you say someone is a ”非常熟的人“？

Tags: grammar

I know that you can say something like "我跟她很熟“。 But can you make someone into a very 熟的人。 
ex。 
他们是我在大学最熟的人

Answer (score 3):

1.“我跟她不熟，我最熟的人是你”。

2.“谁跟你熟啊！我都不认识你”。

3.“对,我们是最熟悉的陌生人”。

4.“熟人好办事，先混熟再说”。

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. This is 100% correct.

> 他们是我在大学最熟的人
>
> 他们是我在大学最亲的人
>
> 他们是我在大学最爱的人
>
> 他们是我在大学最恨的人
>
> 他们是我在大学最怕的人

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but a little strange. You can say 他們是我在大學最要好的一群人

Comment: 「熟」isn't strange in Cantonese at all, just saying

Comment: What do you mean by "最要好的”

Answer (score 2):

It's absolutely right in grammar, but you'd better say`我跟他很熟`.

Answer (score 2):

This is from a Xiangsheng transcript by Guodegang using exactly that form, but in a slightly different context (talking about the audience that arrived).  Some are familiar people, some are not:

> 郭：有人认识我们，有人不认识我们。
>
> 于：哎，有熟的有不熟的。

6th line:
http://blog.sina.com.cn/s/blog_48aa636801008xqc.html

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can say
"他们是我在大学里最亲近的人"
"他们是我在大学里来往最多的人"

Answer (score 1):

use 熟悉 instead of just 熟, otherwise it sounds awkward, at least to the native Chinese.

However, if you want to mean "close," 親近 is better.

Answer (score 0):

Sure,你当然可以说，她是我最熟的人。这里的熟是熟悉的意思，不是烹饪上的煮熟的熟。